# Pop up messagebox not appearing . I know I lack something but I cant figure it out

Tags: java, jframe

I know I lack something but I cant figure it out.
This is my NewJFrame.java(JFrame Form) on Assign.java so far. There must be a window to appear, but it only says successful build. Thanks in advance . Any comment / suggestion is appreciated.

```
    package assign;
    public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        q1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        q2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        q3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        a1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        a2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mid = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        fin = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        g = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jb = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Quizzes");

        jLabel2.setText("Asssignments");

        jLabel3.setText("midterm");

        jLabel4.setText("Finals");

        jLabel5.setText("Grade: ");

        g.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                gActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jb.setText("jButton1");
        jb.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jbActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(q3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(q1)
                    .addComponent(q2))
                .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(a1)
                            .addComponent(a2))
                        .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(mid))
                        .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(fin)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jb)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(g, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(80, 80, 80)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(q1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(a1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(mid, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(fin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(q2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(a2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(q3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(g, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jb))
                .addGap(23, 23, 23))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void gActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  



    }                                 

    private void jbActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
        //mysimplecodeishere      
            double q1b = Double.parseDouble(q1.getText());
                double q2b = Double.parseDouble(q1.getText());
                double q3b = Double.parseDouble(q3.getText());
                double a1b = Double.parseDouble(a1.getText());
                double a2b = Double.parseDouble(a2.getText());
                double m1 = Double.parseDouble(mid.getText());
                double f1 = Double.parseDouble(fin.getText());


                double finsub = f1 * 0.45;

                double midsub = m1 * 0.15;

                double qave = (q1b + q2b + q3b) / 3;

                double aave = (a1b + a2b) / 2;

                double standing = (aave + qave) * 0.6;

                double grade = finsub + midsub + standing;

                String finalgrade;

                g.setText("" + grade);
    }                                  

    public void main(String args[]) {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField a1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField a2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fin;
    private javax.swing.JTextField g;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jb;
    private javax.swing.JTextField mid;
    private javax.swing.JTextField q1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField q2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField q3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` method declaration is wrong.

You have this:

`public void main(String args[]) {`

It should be this:

> public **static** void main(String args[]) {

Update:

[image: Here's a Screenhot from my run]

Comment: It'd be a good time to use the "close as typo" flag reason since...this is *literally* just a typo.

Comment: I already put the word static, but still there are no windows appearing..

Comment: edit: 
There has to be a pop up window where I'm going to input sample grades, but it does not pop, the output only displays successful build.

Comment: @LanceDeCastro, I was able to run this on eclipse just by inserting the word `static` Are you actually trying to run it or just building it? If you're using Netbeans IDE, can you hit *Shift + F6* key to run the file?

Comment: Thanks anacron :) Im just a  beginner on java, please do understand.